# No lines read from text file when using 'readline' for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I have a Node app in a directory together with a text file called **sample.csv**.

I'm trying to read the file line-by-line with the following code, but nothing gets read:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');    

var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
   input: fs.createReadStream('sample.csv')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    console.log(line); // Never happens
});

console.log('Completed.'); // Immediately skips to this
```

Any bright ideas? :) Thanks!

Comment: Check the example from [npm readline page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Max!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var readline = require('linebyline'),
        rl = readline('./sample.csv');
    rl.on('line', function (line, lineCount, byteCount) {
        console.log(lineCount, line, byteCount);
        // do something with the line of text
    })
    .on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("error", e);
        // something went wrong
    });
```

**Node Cheat** Available at [line_by_line](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/line_by_line.js).

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I had a `process.exit()´ immediately after hooking up to the 'line' event... :( I'm guessing my original code probably would've worked, but regardless it seems 'linebyline' is the better option. Thanks again!

Comment: make sure file contains some csv content and it is in same dir, because I have just tested and added sample csv file in node-cheat link. If needed you can try that too. My sample [sample_csv.csv](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/sample_files/sample_csv.csv)